# Компиляция в exe из DLL

Tags: c#, bat, dll

Есть задача: создать .dll, которая будет компилировать код .bat-файла, находящегося в textbox1. Как это сделать?

Comment: На пальцах разъясните. Что скомпилировать (пример), во что?

Comment: Есть textbox1 в нем есть код .bat 
КоД
msg * my app 
Хочу его через .dll скомпилировать в .exe файл.

Comment: Он хочет написать свой компилятор и засунуть его в DLL , что бы на вход длл подавался БАТ а на выходе имелся екзешник.
Удачи.

Comment: тёзка, а для чего такое извращение? почему просто не сохранить содержимое текстбокса в .bat (и запустить)?

Comment: Не так мне не надо я хочу скомпилировать .exe файл!

Comment: @Влад: ну, скажите нам зачем именно вам нужен именно exe-файл. Может, тогда мы сможем лучше понять, что вам на самом деле надо. Потому что сейчас, честно говоря, кажется, что вам нужно что-то гораздо проще. И ещё, что вы будете делать с DLL-кой? Она ж сама по себе не запустится.

Comment: [не знаю почему, но напомнило][1]


  [1]: http://habrahabr.ru/post/130362/

Comment: @teanЫЧ

      [] Пока что самая выдающаяся программа на Вашем языке — это компилятор Вашего языка

Есть язык Haskell, а самая большая программа, на нём написанная -- Glasgow haskell compiler (а язык вроде самый мощный и красивый из современных)

Comment: @alexlz, это ссылка на перевод юмористической статьи. Не смотря на то, что в любой шутке есть доля правды, вы уверены, что стоит воспринимать указанную мной статью на полном серьезе? Я, конечно, понимаю, кто на брейнфаке кодил, тот в цирке не смеется, но неужели все так запущено?

Comment: @teanЫЧ Дык про эту долю и речь.

Comment: @alexlz, в любом случае хаскель я не ферхштейн, а над статьей я просто похихикал расслабившись. Если для вас это принципиально, можете добавить комментарий прямо на хабре, или даже найти автора статьи и поговорить с ним лично.

Comment: @teanЫЧ На хабр, разговаривать с автором... Да, эта шутка покруче будет.

Comment: @alexlz, старался

Answer (score 5):

[[@teanЫЧ](/users/5098/tean%D1%8B%D1%87)](/users/5098/tean%D1%8B%D1%87), по сути Вы наверняка правы, только вот сформулированная автором задача имеет решение (хотя автор наверняка думал не о нем).

--

Пишем на C/C++ компилятор  языка BAT-файлов и реализуем его в виде функции, которую помещаем в .dll. На выходе (естественно линкер вызывается из той же функции) получаем .exe в заданном файле.

Далее очевидно.

Answer (score 4):

Для начала: 
 1. почитайте про [компиляцию и компиляторы](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%CA%EE%EC%EF%E8%EB%FF%F2%EE%F0), судя по всему вы не до конца понимаете, что это такое
 2. почитайте про [dll](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dll), ---//---
 3. почитайте про [bat-файлы](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB), ---//---

*ссылки на педовикию могут быть не самыми удачными, но в них есть ссылки на другие источники. В любом случае, при желании можно погуглить...

Идем дальше.

> создать .dll, которая будет компилировать

DLL не может ничего скомпилировать. Компилирует компилятор (а я наказываю, жестоко наказываю...). Dll - это динамически подключаемая библиотека, используемая исполняемым файлом, в которой содержатся некие ресурсы/функции/и тд.

> будет компилировать код .bat-файла, находящегося в textbox1

У вас код в текстбоксе находится или батник? (чего только не бывает в нашем дремучем лесу)

> Как это сделать?

Судя по всему, описанная Вами задача не подлежит решению. Если Вы все-таки считаете, что это можно сделать, то нормально опишите то, что вы хотите сделать, ибо мы ничего не поняли.

Comment: @avp, сформулированная Вами задача имеет решение. Сформулированная автором - нет. Может он это и имел ввиду, но описание не отражает его мыслей. Я дал свой ответ не под ваш комментарий, а под задачу, описанную автором :)

Comment: @teanЫЧ, я тоже думаю, что автор имел в виду что-то другое. Я же просто формально подошел к написанному им набору слов и известным мн технологиям.

Comment: @avp, вы бы лучше оформили свой комментарий, как ответ. Лично мне он показался интересным.